# How to change the style of whole file in emacs cc mode ?

Tags: emacs, coding-style, emacs24, cc-mode

I am new to emacs and have a C file which is presently in `gnu` style in cc-mode. I have changed the style to `linux` by making the necessary changes in the `.emacs` file.

I want to change the style of whole file (the prewritten code) to the style `linux`. I am unable to do so.

I have tried reindenting the entire file, but it is not working. (although, the code I add after setting the style does come in `linux` style)

Here is the code which I added in `.emacs` file to change the style to linux.

```
(setq c-default-style "linux"
      c-basic-offset 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Perform these steps:

1. Go to the top of the buffer via `(beginning-of-buffer)`, typically bound to `M-<`.
2. Go to the very bottom of the buffer via `(end-of-buffer)`, typically bound to `M->`. This sets a mark at the top of the buffer, then moves to the bottom.
3. Execute the `indent-region` function, typically bound to `C-M-\`.

The final step will indent the region, which will be the entire buffer.

Comment: Alternatively, `mark-whole-buffer` (`C-x h` by default) and then `indent-region` (step 3 in this answer).

Comment: @ps06756 are there any customization settings in the file that are keeping the style set to `gnu` or are setting different indentation levels? If you use `C-h v` to get the value of `c-default-style` and again to get the value of `c-basic-offset` when in that buffer, what values do you see? What style does the mode line for that buffer indicate?